# Set Headers with jQuery.ajax and JSONP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, header

I am trying to access google docs with jQuery.  Here's what I have so far:

```
var token = "my-auth-token";
$.ajax({
  url: "http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full?max-results=1&alt=json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  }
});
```

It doesn't allow me to set headers if I set the `dataType` to `jsonp` (from [Make Cross Domain Ajax Requests with jQuery](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2010/02/26/Make-cross-domain-Ajax-requests-with-jQuery.aspx)).  If I leave out `jsonp`, I can't make the cross-domain request.  If I use `jQuery.getJSON`, I can't pass in any headers...

Is there any way to define custom headers when making a cross-domain ajax request (in jQuery)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is not possible.

A JSONP request works by creating a `<script>` element with its `src` attribute set to the request URL.
You cannot add custom headers to the HTTP request sent by a `<script>` element.

Comment: thanks, great to know.  follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073336/how-to-make-cross-domain-requests-in-jquery-and-set-custom-headers.