# Making jQuery $.ajax call to Twitter API 1.1 search

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

Here is a very simple example of a call to Twitter's search API to get all tweets from a tag known to have tweets, #fml.

I believe I am correctly using the application-only authentication as explained here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth (see Step 3 for example of a call)

I am being asked for a solution that does not involve any server-side code so I am including the bearer code in the javascript, which isn't good to begin with, but....

I would expect this code to work. Instead it produces the error '400 (Bad Request)'. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: "q=%23fml",
    beforeSend:  function (xhr) { 
             xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer XXmyBearerCodeXX"); 
            },
    success: function(json){ alert(json); }
});
```

**EDIT 1 - Validated Twitter call**

Using [hurl.eu](http://hurl.eu) I was able to get a successful response from the API with the above query and Authorization header, so I assume this means my Twitter call is correct, just not set up correctly within jQuery.ajax(), but I just don't see what is missing.

Comment: I don't see any API key being sent

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I guess I thought that since the consumer key is encoded within the bearer code I didn't need to pass another API key. Which key should be sent and where?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, just to make sure I tried the call with nothing but the bearer code through hurl and it does return data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set request headers using AJAX calls with dataType JSONP.

See this question: [Set Headers with jQuery.ajax and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073287/set-headers-with-jquery-ajax-and-jsonp)

The best solution is to use a server-side proxy to do the search for you. I know you are looking for a client only solution, but with this restriction, and with no way around CORS, this is how it seems to be done today for the Twitter API.

**Edit** It may be possible using a proxy like [Yahoo's YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) if you don't have access to one.

Comment: Great info...not the answer I was looking to hear though :(

Answer (score 0):

on your severside create a jsp or servlet and from the client side make a JSON call to the .jsp/servlet and that will return back the json object to the javascript. In serverside use the twitter4j api.
sample code:
`

```
$.getJSON(http://localhost:8080/test.jsp?callback=?",
            {
                jspqueryStr : queryStr,
                jspgeocodeStr : geocodeStr,
                lat:latStr,
                lan:lngStr, 
                radius:radiusStr,
            }, displayResult);
//This function returns the data as json object from server.
function displayResult(data) {}
```

`In the jsp the code is like below`

```
<%
String jspqueryStr = request.getParameter("jspqueryStr");
String jspgeocodeStr = request.getParameter("jspgeocodeStr");
String diseasename = request.getParameter("jspqueryStr");
String lat = request.getParameter("lat");
String lan = request.getParameter("lan");
String radius = request.getParameter("radius");

Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(tweetList);
json = request.getParameter("callback") + "(" + json + ");";
out.println(json);

public List<Status> searchstream(){
//here all the twitter4j api code to get the data 
retrun tweetList;
}

%>
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in this particular case I do not have the ability to use any server-side code.